# Issues redirecting in Django

Tags: python, django, url, redirect

I'm deploying a django app, and I have two forms: One for rating and another for contact in the home page. Both of them redirect to the home page after save a model. The contact form works fine, but the rating form keeps the post url and doesn't save the model, and after doing it again, it save it.
For example, I'm in www.site.com, then I send a post request from the rating form, the form redirect me to www.site.com/rating/ without saving the data. Then, if I'm send from www.site.com/rating/ the same form, the data is saved and redirect to www.site.com/rating/rating/ (404). The contact form works fine with the same process, and I think both are similar. The contact form redirects me to www.site.com like I want. I don't know why is this happening.
urls.py

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    url(r'^', include('myapp.urls')),
    prefix_default_language=False
)
```

myapp/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^rating/', views.raiting, name='rating'),
    url(r'^', views.index, name='home'),
]
```

myapp/views.py

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        raise Http404('acceding from GET')

    msg = ContactForm(request.POST)
    if not msg.is_valid():
        context = {
            'contact_errors': msg.errors
        }
        return render(request, 'home.html', context)
    msg.save()
    return redirect('home')


def rating(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        raise Http404('acceding from GET')

    msg_form = OpinionForm(request.POST)
    if not msg_form.is_valid():
        context = {
            'rating_errors': msg_form.errors
        }
        return render(request, 'home.html', context)
    msg = msg_form.save(commit=False)
    if 'picture' in request.FILES:
        msg.picture = request.FILES['picture']
    msg.save()
    return redirect('home')
```

the forms in home.html

```
<form action="{% url 'rating' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name" required>
    <textarea name="text" id="" cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Your comment" required></textarea>
    <input name="picture" type="file" id="upload-photo">
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Send"> 
</form>

<form action="{% url 'contact' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="email" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
    <textarea name="message" id="" cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control" required placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Send">
</form>
```

Comment: Check if the rating form is actually valid when you first submit it. It could be that the form is invalid, the template's form action attribute then sends you to `site/rating`, then the form is valid and the form action does it's thing again by sending you to `site/rating/rating`.

Comment: I checked that, and the form is valid

Answer (score 0):

I guess that this is a typo, but check your urls.py:

```
url(r'^rating/', views.raiting, name='rating'),
```

should be rating instead o raiting, right?